# Pass an absolute path as preprocessor directive on compiler command line

Tags: c++, visual-studio, command-line, macros, c-preprocessor

I'd like to pass a MSVC++ 2008 macro into my program via a `/D` define like so

```
/D__HOME__="\"$(InputDir)\""
```

then in my program I could do this

```
cout << "__HOME__ => " << __HOME__ << endl;
```

which should print something like

```
__HOME__ => c:\mySource\Directory
```

but it doesn't like the back slashes so I actually get:

```
__HOME__ => c:mySourceDirectory
```

Any thoughts on how I could get this to work?

**UPDATE**: I finally got this to work with Tony's answer below but note that the `$(InputDir)` contains a trailing backslash so the actual macro definition has to have an extra backslash to handle it ... hackery if ever I saw it!

```
/D__HOME__="\"$(InputDir)\\""
```

Comment: This is a command/shell question, not a C++ question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert your macro to a string by prefixing it with the stringizing operator #. However, this only works in macros. You actually need a double-macro to make it work properly, otherwise it just prints `__HOME__`.

```
#define STRINGIZE2(x) #x
#define STRINGIZE(x) STRINGIZE2(x)
cout<< "__HOME__ => " << STRINGIZE(__HOME__) << endl;
```

Incidentally macros containing double underscores are reserved to the implementation in C++, and should not be used in your program.

Comment: Hey thanks for the pointer Anthony and I've changed the define to HOME_DIR, however I get an "error C2014: preprocessor command must start as first nonwhite space" using your solution.

Comment: I've edited my comment to do it properly done with the double macro trick.

Comment: Note that if you already use Boost, you can use `BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE`.